# Cannot define Backbone with requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I've done it before, so I must be stupid or something. Can you see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
requirejs.config({

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'vendor/require-jquery',
        'jquery-ui': 'vendor/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min',
        'modernizr': 'vendor/modernizr-2.6.1.min',
        'nivoslider': 'vendor.nivo.slider.pack',
        'chosen': 'vendor/chosen.jquery.min',
        'backbone': 'vendor/backbone.min',
        'underscore': 'vendor/underscore.min',
        'consolefix': 'consolefix'
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'modernizr', 'backbone'], function($, modernizr, Backbone) {
    var model = Backbone.Model.extend();
    console.log(model);
});
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined

Comment: Are you using [this version](https://github.com/amdjs) of Backbone/Underscore?

Comment: Could you remove nivoslider, chosen and consolefix and see if it helps? Here's my JSFiddle that tried to replicate what you have... and it seems to be OK: http://jsfiddle.net/dashk/jzgWM/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change `requirejs.config` to `require.config`, it should work.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier backbone.min.js:43`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined boot.js:23`

Comment: You might want to `console.log(Backbone)` to see if `Backbone` contains any data.

Comment: Umm, might want to try replacing the `backbone.min.js` you're using ?

Answer (score 0):

You should define jquery and uderscore as shim as well.

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rely on `shim` to get the value back. Just use the global Backbone once it loads.

See this, somewhat similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14715393/366864